# How to get <p> element values in XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-parsing, screen-scraping

```
XDocument coordinates = XDocument.Load("http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch");
System.IO.StreamWriter StreamWriter1 = new System.IO.StreamWriter(DestFile);
XNamespace nsContent = "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/";
foreach (var item in coordinates.Descendants("item"))
{
   string link = item.Element("guid").Value;
   string content = item.Element(nsContent + "encoded").Value; //It gets all links, images etc 
}

StreamWriter1.Close();
```

using this i can get `guid` element values as well as `content:encoded` values but the value of `content:encoded` element gets all the links,  tags,

tags etc.

But i want the text only...Means i need the **simple text data** only and not need to get any img links, links etc.

How can i parse the `<p>..</p>` tag data in XML ?
Please suggest
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you have HTML embeded in that XML document.  The safest thing to do would be to take that HTML and parse it using an HTML parser such as the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and go from there.  It shouldn't be that much different.  Do note that the HTML is still encoded a bit so you'll have to decode it first.

```
const string url = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch";
var doc = XDocument.Load(url);
var items = doc.Descendants("item");
XNamespace nsContent = "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/";
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var encodedContent = (string)item.Element(nsContent + "encoded");
    var decodedContent = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(encodedContent);
    var html = new HtmlDocument();
    html.LoadHtml(decodedContent);
    var ps = html.DocumentNode.Descendants("p");
    foreach (var p in ps)
    {
        var textContent = p.InnerText;
        // do something with textContent
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the HTML doesn't seem to be very well-formed XML so you won't be able to use LINQ to XML with that part.

Comment: Wow it worked fine for me...But what if i want to store all p values in one string varialble.. ?like should i use StringBuilder ?

Answer (score 1):

Use an xpath, something like:

```
//p
```

That should do it for the xpath query. [Here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314758/parsing-xml-with-xdocument-and-xpath) for the library you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Once you identify the content string, you've got a few different options:

1. Use regular expressions to isolate and remove anything within tags. This will remove all tags from the text and would (in theory) leave you with only the text if that's what you are interested in.
2. Parse the text itself and construct a text output. I've done something similar in this powershell script (https://github.com/joelmartinez/PowerShell-Bits/blob/master/GetTextFromHtml.ps1). I load some HTML into a dom using the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), and then walk the dom tree to pull out text nodes.

Comment: So why is it being pulled out as text? `string content = item.Element(nsContent + "encoded").Value`. Either way, doesn't matter, the answer stands as is. the HtmlAgilityPack works really well at handling HTML (which may be malformed if the source is sloppy)

Comment: Oops, my mistake, it is XML but there's some HTML embedded in there which I didn't initially see.